# Open filename of format using Glob and OS

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, glob

The filename will be different every time, but the naming convention is the same.

Based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory), I want to open a filename of this example format:

```
20211201-095143.json
```

I don't want it to get confused with:

```
20211201-095143_metadata.json
```

**Code:**

```
import os
import glob

filenames = glob.glob(''.join([os.listdir(DIR), '*-*.json']))
filenames

with open(filenames[0]) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f1a73e787764> in <module>
----> 1 filenames = glob.glob(''.join([os.listdir(DIR), '*-*.json']))
      2 filenames

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I should clarify.

Comment: I think you meant to use `glob.glob(os.path.join(DIR, "*.json"))`, you get a list from that command and you can for example use regex or if you always have the keyword `metadata` even simple list comprehension to exclude files containing metadata

Comment: Working now Thanks